# Test pass on Android 6.0 but fail on Android 8.0 - androidx.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'single click

Tags: android, android-espresso, ui-testing

Android Studio 3.3

I has two edit fields and one button. If click button and not filled all fields than shot toast with error message - `Please, input all fields`

Here app/build.gradle:

```
    ext.ESPRESSO_VERSION = '3.2.0-alpha02'
    androidTestCompile 'com.azimolabs.conditionwatcher:conditionwatcher:0.2'

    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$ESPRESSO_VERSION"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$ESPRESSO_VERSION"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$ESPRESSO_VERSION"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:rules:$ANDROIDX_TEST"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:runner:$ANDROIDX_TEST"
    androidTestImplementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:3.8.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Here layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/jsonViewToolBar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar"
            android:title='@{@string/add_trader}'
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/baseTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/half_default_margin"
            android:text="@string/base"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_view_text_size"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/jsonViewToolBar" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/baseTextInputEditText"
            style="@style/textViewOneLine"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/edit_text_text_size"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/baseTextView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/baseTextView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/baseTextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quoteTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:text="@string/quote"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_view_text_size"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/baseTextView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/baseTextView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/baseTextInputEditText" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/quoteTextInputEditText"
            style="@style/textViewOneLine"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/edit_text_text_size"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/baseTextView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/baseTextView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/quoteTextView" />


        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/startButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/min_height"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="@{() -> handler.onClickStart()}"
            android:text="@string/start"
            android:textSize="@dimen/tool_bar_text_size"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/baseTextView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/baseTextView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/quoteTextInputEditText"
            app:textAllCaps="true" />

        <include
            layout="@layout/progress_bar_layout"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

Here Espresso's test:

```
@Test
    fun onlyQuoteFill_buttonStart_click() {
        onView(withId(baseTextInputEditText)).perform(clearText())
        onView(withId(quoteTextInputEditText)).perform(typeText(QUOTE_TEST))
        onView(withId(startButton))
                .perform(click())
        onView(withText(please_input_all_fields)).inRoot(ToastMatcher())
                .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }
```

And this test success pass on **emulators Android 5.0, 6.0, 7.0**

Nice.

But when I start this test on emulator Android 8.0 its fail with error message:

```
$ adb shell am instrument -w -r   -e debug false -e class 'com.myproject.AddTraderActivityTest#onlyQuoteFill_buttonStart_click' com.myproject.debug.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
Client not ready yet..
Started running tests

androidx.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'single click - At Coordinates: 239, 427 and precision: 16, 16' on view 'with id: com.myproject.debug:id/startButton'.
at androidx.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:84)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:87)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:59)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.waitForAndHandleInteractionResults(ViewInteraction.java:316)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.desugaredPerform(ViewInteraction.java:177)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:118)
at com.myproject.AddTraderActivityTest.onlyQuoteFill_buttonStart_click(AddTraderActivityTest.kt:447)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:80)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:61)
at androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:531)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:104)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:392)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2075)
Caused by: androidx.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'Send down motion event' on view 'unknown'.
at androidx.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:84)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.sendDown(MotionEvents.java:127)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.sendSingleTap(Tap.java:168)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.access$100(Tap.java:31)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap$1.sendTap(Tap.java:47)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction.perform(GeneralClickAction.java:136)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:360)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:251)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.access$100(ViewInteraction.java:64)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:157)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:154)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
Caused by: androidx.test.espresso.InjectEventSecurityException: java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission
at androidx.test.espresso.base.InputManagerEventInjectionStrategy.innerInjectMotionEvent(InputManagerEventInjectionStrategy.java:164)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.InputManagerEventInjectionStrategy.innerInjectMotionEvent(InputManagerEventInjectionStrategy.java:162)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.InputManagerEventInjectionStrategy.injectMotionEvent(InputManagerEventInjectionStrategy.java:130)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.EventInjector.injectMotionEvent(EventInjector.java:92)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl$3.call(UiControllerImpl.java:229)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl$3.call(UiControllerImpl.java:226)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2004)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1950)
at android.hardware.input.IInputManager$Stub$Proxy.injectInputEvent(IInputManager.java:636)
at android.hardware.input.InputManager.injectInputEvent(InputManager.java:925)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.InputManagerEventInjectionStrategy.innerInjectMotionEvent(InputManagerEventInjectionStrategy.java:146)
... 11 more


Tests ran to completion.
```

Here settings of Android 8.0 settings:

[image]

Here screenshot on Android 6.0.

[image]

And here screenshot on Android 8.0
[image]

P.S. When click button **Start** I don't hide soft keyboard.

P.P.S. After I start test on Android 8.0 with more density **xhdpi** then test **SUCCESS PASS**.

Here screen shot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Indicates that an exception occurred while performing a ViewAction on
> the UI thread.
>
> A description of the ViewAction, the view being performed on and the
> cause are included in the error. Note: FailureHandlers can mutate the
> exception later to make it more user friendly.
>
> This is generally not recoverable so it is thrown on the
> instrumentation thread.

More at [PerformException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/PerformException)

Comment: I found solution. I add ScrollView in layout and In production code when focus on second edit text I programmatically scroll down to bottom of screen. And as result now test is success pass.

Comment: post it as an answer and confirm it in 2 days

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. I add `ScrollView` in layout and In production code when focus on second edit text I programmatically scroll down to bottom of screen. As result now button `Start` is **full visible**. And as result now test is **success pass**.